# Problem with software-center in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-center, update-manager

I installed Ubuntu trusty 14.04 on my laptop along side windows dual boot.
i have a problem with software center. i am unable to install any tool using this and also no updates were taking place. So i removed this software center and tried to re install it. 
i used these codes
`sudo apt-get remove software-center`
then it removed. while i am trying to reinstall it using
`sudo apt-get install software-center`
it is showing

`E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate`

please help me.I need to install meep on this.

Comment: edit your question and post the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Comment: How can i get that /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: open a terminal and type and enter the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I am unable to paste the entire file into edit. it is showing you need atleast 10 reputations to post more than 2 links.

Comment: BUt when i pasted the entire thing in edit, it showed that this software is unsupported from Ubuntu team. i did not understand why this happened. I downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 from www.ubuntu.com/download   .

Comment: Copy the content and paste in a note in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/). Then share link

Answer (score 1):

First use `sudo apt-get update` command before using `sudo apt-get install software-center`. If it still shows the same error, try to enable the **main** component of Ubuntu official repository. Get help from this similar question [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Though the main part should always be enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked. now i can install everything i want.